# Is there a way to get notifications using Sharepoint REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, rest, onedrive-for-business

I have created Sharepoint provider-hosted app.

With the App only token, I want to get the notifications for file addition , file deletion , file shared ..,etc for all users(onedrive sites) in a domain

I tried looking into the documentation but I couldn't find any API.

Does Sharepoint REST API supports notifications ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you are looking for are Remote Event Receivers  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220048.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Notifications are called Event Receivers in SharePoint, but as far as I remember you can't add these using REST, but you have to use CSOM and add them for each site.